# Hibernate fast unhibernate slow with new SSHD Hybrid drive

Tags: windows-7, hibernate, thinkpad

I recently replaced my HDD (Lenovo X220 laptop, Win7 x64, intel i7, 6GB Ram) with a hybrid SSD/HDD drive (500GB Seagate SATA 2.5-inch Solid State Hybrid Drive (SSHD) 6Gbps 5400rpm).

The system speed improved as expected, and particularly hibernate is now quite fast.

But oddly, restoring from hibernate (unhibernate?) is now much slower, on the order of 10 minutes.

I have no idea why this would be and don't know what settings to look at. Any ideas?

Comment: Not a duplicate I think. That one says "It spends minutes on a black screen with a blinking cursor, longer than to restart. It is also glacially slow to start programs after startup." I don't see that. Unhibernate on mine doesn't have a black screen. It unhibernates normally, just takes much longer than before I changed harddisks. Also programs run fine after startup for me.

Comment: I suspect that maybe my problem is some setting not optimized for the new SSHD.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem with my Seagate Thin SSHD 500GB and Toshiba laptop on Windows XP: unhibernate in up to 6 minutes on 2GB of RAM after moving to new disk.

A solution that worked for me was to disable system services which I considered junk: sevices from vendors other than Microsoft that seemd not critical (ie. Java Quick Start, Google Update, Serviio, Intel services and about 10 others). I don't know which of them exactly caused the problem but after doing so my unhibernate is fast again (10 seconds).
I've found [this](http://forums.anandtech.com/archive/index.php/t-2190000.html) article very helpful.